# Encrypting XML in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, encryption

I have a scenario where I send XML files from a server to an application.

I want to ensure that only the application can read the XML content, i.e. not only should the communication itself be secure but when the client has received the encrypted XML then **only the application should be able to read and use its content**.

As I am not very familiar with encryption I would appreciate some directions on how I can go about achieving this?

I have looked at [How to: Encrypt XML Elements with Asymmetric Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746.aspx). However, I do not quite understand how the client gets the decryption key. The example seems to use a `KeyContainer` which stores both the public and private the key when its generated before encryption, how would that work when run on different machines? I guess I could generate the key once, and then save the public part to an xml, however, then anyone that has the xml could decrypt messages, including the user of the client application? Is there a way where I can embed in a secure fashion the public key into the client application?

Comment: If both parties (client & server) can keep a shared secret, it may be easier to implement.

Comment: @SimonMourier: That is possible, the question is, how would I securely store the shared secret client side so that only the application has access to it?

Comment: In theory, you can't. If it can run it can be hacked. You can just make it difficult. If the client can't be protected, you'll have to use asymmetric algorithm (encrypt using public key, decrypt using private key)